# Why does iotop not show the same as iostat? Why is there a difference?

Tags: linux, monitoring, io

On my Raspbian 8 (Jessie) system

```
iostat -dzp 5 |grep -v "k0 "
```

shows me

```
:
Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
mmcblk0p2         0.80         0.00         3.20          0         16
Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
:
```

while

```
sudo iotop -btoqqqd 5
```

does not show anything at the same time. Why?

It seems like this problem has been seen before: [iotop does not show writes](https://serverfault.com/q/487418/330169).

I have reported this as bug to Debian: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=856186.

Comment: I don't suspect `iotop` to catch ALL I/O, but rather taking snapshots at regular intervals (as implied by its name, io + top). If you want to catch everything you'd rather go the auditing route, maybe look at something like [osquery](https://osquery.io/).

Answer (score 1):

`iotop` is obviously missing the I/Os for some reason.

If your kernel has [ftrace](http://elinux.org/Ftrace) enabled, I would recommend using Brendan Gregg's [iosnoop](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/iosnoop) port to Linux ftrace available here to figure out what is responsible for the writes.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be a powerful tool. However it doesn't seem to show activity if add lines to a file with `date >>test`. So I am still missing I/O.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation given in the discussion of the bug report is that

> - The processes that are doing writes disappearing before the timer.

This makes sense. Whether this is the expected behavior is under discussion.